# What's a permalink used for?

Tags: discussion, permalink

I didn't see anything different whether or not to permallink to a question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Can you rephrase?

Comment: Don't you see a "permallink to this answer" under each answer?

Comment: @Nathan Fellman,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384762/i18n-validations/1504843#1504843

Answer (score 10):

"permalink" just means direct hyperlink, the basic building block of the web.

You can "permalink" to a **question** by clicking the question title (or right clicking the title and selecting "copy link"):

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/whats-a-permalink-used-for`

You can also right click the "share" menu item underneath a question and select "copy link". In that case, you'll get a personalized link (one with your user ID embedded in it). [Pass this around to win coveted badges!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/)

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24456/<userid>
```

You can "permalink" to an **answer** by clicking the "share" menu item next to it (or right clicking the "share" menu item and selecting "copy link"). This ensures you get a link that works no matter what sorting is used, and no matter how many pages of answers a question has:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24457/<userid>
```

If you click (rather than right-click) the "share" link on a post, you'll get a popup that allows you to copy the link AND handy tools for sharing it directly on several popular social media services:

> [image]

Comment: So it's just used to locate the answer under a question?

Comment: Pretty much - but it is very useful... For example, if you are referring to something and say look at xx's answer on this page... No scrolling needed, they can just go straight to the answer... There are better examples, but can't quickly think of them!

Comment: @Jeff: we seem to have migrated the bot from SO to MSO...

Comment: @Wil it's incredibly useful on questions with enough answers that it has to page, with the permalink it will take you directly to that page (and that answer on that page) automatically - eg, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c/1724852#1724852  (this is normally on the middle of page 4 when sorted by votes)

Answer (score 1):

The "link" under each answer is just that, a link directly to that answer.  It was added as a convenience, so that if you wish to reference that answer in another answer or question, you could just right-click on it to copy the URL.  Prior to this you had to look up that answer on the user's profile page and copy the link from there.