# Is the 'permalink' link-button not working?

Tags: support, bug, permalink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a permalink used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/whats-a-permalink-used-for)

I tried clicking the 'Link' button to create a permalink to a post but nothing happens - the page just refreshes.  I thought that I had accidentally clicked it before and saw a little pop-up with urls but that isn't happening for me anymore.  Is something broken or is how the "Link" button is supposed to work?

I tried looking to see if anyone else had this issue on meta but can't find it (if you do find one let me know).

Comment: Hmm, that's funny.  Usually for me, clicking `link` will load the permalink and I C&P it from the address bar.  However, upon trying to link this question, it just refreshed the page.

Comment: See: [What does the “link” thingy do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18635/what-does-the-link-thingy-do) and [What's a permalink used for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/whats-a-permalink-used-for) (FWIW, there's [a little box that pops up occasionally](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) as sort of an *encouragement* to link to questions that you like... But AFAIK it's the exception, and you don't have to *do* anything but load the page to get it)

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks that helped.  So unless I want to link to an answer I don't even need to click the "link" button - I can just grab the url from the address bar? And if I want to link to an answer then I just click "link" for that answer and copy the url.  There is no pop-up with the link?

Comment: @Shog9 thanks - your edit was perfect - if you add that as an answer I'll select it.

Comment: The link button for a question is the only way to get the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges.

Comment: @John (and Brandon) the "link" link for questions is also different from the URL in the location bar: [it has a referral user id](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink) embedded in it. Copying the link itself is different than the URL from the location bar.

Comment: @Arjan, I forgot about that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for adding that.  After Shog's comment I was curious what the "link" button was for if there was no difference.

Comment: @Daniel: I've added the information to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/whats-a-permalink-used-for/24457#24457), and would prefer to close this question as a duplicate so as to keep that answer as a reference.