# Permalinks feature - how does it work?

Tags: support

Can someone point me to information on how exactly permalinks work?

More to the point: when I click on "link" it displays a link in a pop-up box, when I click 'close', does it make it into a permalink? If not, where do I paste that link? If yes, how do I undo it? Will be much obliged.

Comment: Related: [What's a permalink used for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24456/140951)

Comment: Thanks! That link actually contained the information I needed on how to share those links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links there are shortened versions of a full link, with a reference to your user ID. For example, your question is:

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121121/permalinks-feature-how-does-it-work`

For my account, the permalink for the above is:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121121/162522
```

It shortens `/questions` to `/q` and takes out the text at the end (the "[slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing))"). If you're logged in, it will also append your user ID [for Announcer, Booster, and Publicist Badges](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/). If you don't care about that, or want the link to be anonymous, then remove your user ID:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121121
```

Both versions of the permalink should be permanent as long as you don't delete your question.

The same applies to answers, showing an `a` instead of a `q`.

Comment: The last ID is just your user ID. No condensing... :)

Comment: This is correct.  They're quite straightforward referral links, they don't generate a GUID per-click on "link" or anything like that.